# Printing Pattern Horizontally in Python

Tags: python, logic

So I have to print * in the shape of A which I did.

```
pattern = ""
for row in range(7):
      for col in range(5):
            if ((col==0 or col==4) and row!=0) or ((row==0 or row==3) and (col>0 and col<4)):
                  pattern = pattern + "*"
            else:
                  pattern = pattern + " " 
      pattern = pattern + "\n"
pattern = pattern + " "

print(pattern, end="")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 *** 
*   *
*   *
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
```

But I want to print more A horizontally.
Example: L displayed as star program 3 times looks as below

```
*        *        *
*        *        *
* * *    * * *    * * *
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I did not change a lot in your code, but thought that putting it in a function might be useful. As you can see in the last line, you now just have to call it with the number of letters you want to print. Furthermore, I added a for-loop in between yours, in order to get all the required symbols into the according line.
Lastly, I added an if/else staement that checks this is the end of the row and otherwise does not go into the next line.

```
def multiplePatterns(n):
    pattern = ""
    for row in range(7):
        for i in range(n):
            for col in range(5):
                if ((col==0 or col==4) and row!=0) or ((row==0 or row==3) and (col>0 and col<4)):
                      pattern = pattern + "*"
                else:
                      pattern = pattern + " " 
            if i == n-1:
                pattern = pattern + "\n"
            else:
                pattern += "  "
    pattern = pattern + " "
    return pattern

print(multiplePatterns(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a library like pyfiglet : https://pypi.org/project/pyfiglet/ .

If you want to do it yourself, python console write per line, you must print your text (ex:"AAA") line per line.
if your final goal is just that, then:

```
print(" ***      ***      ***")
print("*   *    *   *    *   *")
print("*   *    *   *    *   *")
print("*****    *****    *****")
print("*   *    *   *    *   *")
print("*   *    *   *    *   *")
print("*   *    *   *    *   *")
```

will do the job.

If your goal is to write any text, then its probably better to create some kind of "font" with each letter in a list.